# New macpro needs to connect with thunderbolt

Tags: thunderbolt

Getting new macpro. Have RAID external drive. I am unsure of the name of the connector but suspect it is thunderbolt not 3. 
I want to buy the correct connector so the data on the drive is available. 
Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks![image]

Comment: It is *VERY* difficult to really see anything from that picture, you may want to give it another try. That said it might be a USB-C/Thunderbolt cable. Best bet for you would be to look for pics of USB-C connectors by Apple on your favorite search engine and see if they match.

Comment: Thanks. I am no photog. It is not a usb c, as it does not fit usb c slots on other devices and it is older. The other end of the cable connects to the external drive that I want to connect to a new macpro.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forums!

The picture makes it out to look like it could be be both USB-C as thunderbolt would be square.

[Here is a link](https://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/) where you can read on apple’s thunderbolt 3 and at the bottom of the article are easy to compare images of what many apple device adapters female ends look like. Go take a look on the site rather than uploading another clear image.